# PHP - Wikipedia style package repository system?

Tags: package

I started using a few general purpose utility packages which I integrate into my projects with composer via packagist. A good one I found is `jbzoo/utils`:
https://github.com/JBZoo/Utils
It has a group of classes with useful methods. I see that some packages have useful methods that others don't, so I created my own package in which I combine the useful classes and methods of various packages, and also add my own methods. I don't have time to setup tests and meet the requirements to become a contributor on github, but it would be great if I could collaborate with others in building packages like this.

Is there a system where users collaborate in building packages in a wikipedia style fashion where anyone can go in there and make improvements and pitch in whatever they want in an open and free way? For example, I could add a few new methods, then the next programmer might take a look at the methods, see some potential problems and improve the methods. Another programmer may decide to spare a bit of time to write up tests for the methods and classes written by the previous programmer etc.

I realise this comes with some big security risks, but again, using wikipedia as an analogy, most people who use it, use it with the right intentions and the result is wikipedia is a relatively trustworthy source of information. I assume the same principal would apply to this.

Is there a system like this? It would of course be ideal if you could install the packages with composer (or whatever package manager for whatever language the package is written in).

Comment: How would that system differ from git or any other VCS?

Comment: With github, you need to be authorised to modify someone elses package.